# Refresh a certain page in jquery

Tags: jquery

This is an issue bothering in my mind until now if is it possible to refresh/reload a certain page even if you are not in that page. Given a scenario.

I am in page

```
www.try.com/trythis.php
```

I want to refresh a certain page like

```
www.try.com/refreshme.php
```

I know how to refresh a page if you are in that page using `location.reload` or redirect, but I just want to reload a certain page without going to that page or i am not on that page.

Is this possible in jquery? Hope I explain well my question :)

Comment: Use `$.ajax`... with a `get` request, or simpler just use `$.get`. Job done :)

Comment: What is your expected result to refresh a page not displayed? Looks like you just want to call a server side script

Comment: for what reason do you want to refresh the other page?

Comment: its time to change your username.

Comment: guys dont vote down the question, Just thingking if this will be posible and if not then thats the time i had to use `server request`

Comment: +1: There are plenty of reason to want to do this. Down-voting because you can't think of any is silly :)

Comment: @HTTP Why don't you answer questions in comments then? So what are you expecting here??? `refreshing a page not currently displayed` doesn't make much sense

Comment: I think it all in the terminology used. If he had said, "I want to tell the server to refresh something, just not on the current page", everyone would have said "use Ajax!".

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Agreed. "Use Ajax". But, for what? How do we refresh/reload the other page? That is the part which is not clear.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Google would have said that too ;) That's said, checking OP's history, looks like he already knows about ajax so still confusing imho

Comment: Guys, I think I did not explain well my question. Let me rephrase it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('www.try.com/refreshme.php');
```

Preferably use a relative URL (relative to your server hosting the pages I mean) e.g.:

```
$.get('/refreshme.php');
```

This will send an async get request to the server that you can just ignore the result from.

Comment: I translated OP's question like that too ;)